# iosのsafariのみajaxがfailに入る

Tags: javascript, ios, ajax

サーバーに設置しているPHPにajaxでアクセスして、jsonでデータを受け取ることをしているのですが、iosのsafariのみうまくいきません。
fail内容を見ると

XMLHttpRequest.status : 0
　textStatus : error
　errorThrown.message : 'the operation timed out'

とalertで表示されているので、

```
jQuery.ajax({
    async : false,
    url : 'PHP' ,
    type : 'POST',
    dataType : "json",
    timeout: 0,
    cache: false,
    data : 'p=aaa&q=bbb
})
```

とtimeoutやcacheの指定をしてもダメでした。

PHP側の処理はjson_encode($data);でjsonで返していて、$dataの中にも値があることは確認してます。
pcのchromeやAndroidのchromeは問題ないく動作しjsonの値が受け取れているのですが、原因となるようなことはないでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2019/4時点でiosのsafariがajaxのtimeoutの設定が無効化しているようで、設定を短くしても、長くしても、10秒ほどで自動的に処理を中断するようでした。
PHP側は入力したURLの存在確認のためfile_get_contentsを利用していたのですが、特定のURLでのレスポンスが10秒以上かかることがわかりました。（サイトのスクレイピング対策？）
curlに変更することで一旦回避することができました。